# Insert in postgress directly works but with Sequalize it does not

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

I have a project in node js with sequalize connected to a database.

The issue I'm facing is that when I insert in the database directly works but in sequalize it says something like:

"Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: el valor null para la columna «id_p» viola la restricción not null"

First table is persona, second is pasaporte. I have a one to one relationship

[image: Persona]

[image: Contacto]

Here the issue does not happen:

```
persona.create({ nombre: 'ArnoldoBazaldua', edad: '6' })
```

Here it does:

```
pasaporte.create({ pasaporte_num: '811545531', fidP2: '2' })
```

id_p in models:

Pasaporte:

```
"idP": {
        type: Seq.INTEGER,
        field: "id_p",
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: true,
        unique: "pasaporte_pkey",
        references: "public.persona",
        referencesKey: "id_p"
    },
```

In persona:

```
"idP": {
            type: Seq.INTEGER,
            field: "id_p",
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: "persona_pkey"
        },
```

Foreing key in persona table:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `pasaporte.id_p` is a foreign key to persona`, then

```
persona.createPasaport({ .... }
```

Also `pasaporte.telefono` is not defined.

Comment: the foreign key is fid_p , adding the part of relations

Comment: it was id_p not fid_p like i wanted thanks , yo help me notice